# iOS - "'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found" Error Inside Custom Framework Inside Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have compiled a custom Objective-C Framework which I will be referring to as Custom.framework. I'm having an issue with the files inside the framework when I try to build the project the framework is linked in.

Inside Custom.framework I have my main Header file called Custom.h and the following code is where the problem arises:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
```

I have a recursive framework and library path set up to where my .framework file is located: /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/**

My project and framework files are in /Users/macbook/Sites/

Also my framework appears in red text, but is recognized when I import it if that helps.

Comment: I don't suppose using @import Foundation; instead (and corresponding use of Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)) in your build properties helps.

Comment: Oh wow that did work. I didn't try @import Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

As Glenn Howes states in a comment under the question, I needed to change the import to @import Foundation instead of using #import  and turn on Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) in my build properties (which I already had).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Foundation.framework in Scheme --> Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries?

Comment: Yes. I've added it to both the framework and the project. It still gives me the same error.